# html get request "you didn't select a category"

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, get, httplib

I'm new to http and in need of help. I'm trying to fill out a search form in [craigslist](http://auburn.craigslist.org/) so that I can get the link to the page I would have normally gotten if I had filled out the form manually. By viewing the source, I've found this form:

```
<form id="search" action="/search/" method="GET">
            <div>search craigslist</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="areaID" value="372">
            <input type="hidden" name="subAreaID" value="">
            <input id="query" name="query" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"><br>
            <select id="catAbb" name="catAbb">
                <option value="ccc">community</option>
                <option value="eee">events</option>
                <option value="ggg">gigs</option>
                <option value="hhh">housing</option>
                <option value="jjj">jobs</option>
                <option value="ppp">personals</option>
                <option value="res">resumes</option>
                <option value="sss" selected="selected">for sale</option>
                <option value="bbb">services</option>
            </select>


<input id="go" type="submit" value="&gt;">
    </form>
```

So I wrote this code to fill out the form:

```
import urllib,httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("auburn.craigslist.org")
params = urllib.urlencode({'query': 'english tutor', 'catAbb': 'bbb'})
conn.request("GET","/search",params)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.read()
```

I'm not sure about everything, e.g. how do I specify which form do I want to fill? I assumed it is by specifying "\search" as in the form's "action", but should it really be in the 'url' argument in httplib.request?
Anyway, Instead of getting a url to my desired results page, I get this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>auburn craigslist search</title>
    <blockquote>
        <b>You did not select a category to search.</b>
    </blockquote>
```

But I'm pretty sure I did select a category. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it expects a GET request and not a POST?

Comment: Because it says "method=GET". It's an assumption, is it correct?

Comment: Generally, I recommend using a Browser plugin such as Fiddler to see what exactly happens when you use the normal browser and then to reproduce this programmatically. With Fiddler, you will exactly see the structure of the HTTP GET request as sent by your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send HTTP GET params in the URL (and not as an encoded part of the request body like `POST`), change your Python to look like this and you should get what you are after:

```
import urllib,httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("auburn.craigslist.org")
params = urllib.urlencode({'query': 'english tutor', 'catAbb': 'bbb'})
conn.request("GET","/search?%s" % params)
response = conn.getresponse()

print response.read()
```

Also you it will make your life a lot easier if you pass this input to [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), for parsing and extracting information.

Comment: Seems like it worked, huge thanks! Do you know how can I get the url for the result page, instead of the html code?

Comment: But that means I didn't need an http request at all! :O

Comment: `.request()` fetches the document which has a response as well as other meta data (like headers).  `.getresponse()` returns the HTML from the last request.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests    
response = requests.get("http://auburn.craigslist.org/search/", params={"query": "english tutor", "catAbb": "sss"})
response.content
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I recommend using a Browser plugin such as [HttpFox](http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/) to see what exactly happens when you use the normal browser and then to reproduce this programmatically. With HttpFox, you will exactly see the structure of the HTTP GET request as sent by your browser.

It looks like you need to provide all of these query parameters: `areaID`, `subAreaID`, `query`, `catAbb` (you missed two of those).

The error message of the web application might just as well be not precise/buggy.

Comment: But the first two are "hidden", do I really to provide those? seems unlikely.

Comment: They are hidden in the graphical interface, but sent within the request. That's the purpose of hidden fields. Try it out yourself using e.g. HttpFox.

Answer (score 0):

please try with one of the following

```
    conn.request("GET", "http://auburn.craigslist.org/search/", params)
    conn.request("GET", "/search/", params)
```

Comment: both yield the same result as my original try.